# Salesforce and Pardot vs. Ciphercloud

Tags: integration, pardot

I stumbled upon an architectural question regarding Salesforce.com, [Pardot](http://www.pardot.com/) and [CipherCloud](http://www.ciphercloud.com/).

Once set up Ciphercloud to encrypt data in Salesforce, e.g. personal information like Lead name and Contact information, this data is being encrypted in the cloud and only readable when logging into Salesforce via CipherCloud reverse proxy.

Now when connecting Pardot with Salesforce the pardot connector needs to talk to CipherCloud proxy instead directly to Salesforce. When connecting directly to Salesforce, Pardot only gets the encrypted data which is obviously useless. ;)

I already searched for reference issues but did not find any helpful information. I wonder if I'm maybe missing a key point in understanding.

Did anyone already implemented this use case and if so - how?

Comment: You should be asking Pardot this question as there product needs to be able to handle proxies such as the one CipherCloud uses

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Pardot.

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't clear to me, that this site does not cover questions related to other salesforce products (Pardot is tightly coupled with their sales cloud).

Comment: @mast0r Pardot is owned by Salesforce/Exacttarget, I'd say that makes it on-topic ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Oww, nice to know :( retracted my vote now.

Comment: I am looking to integrate Pardot with Ciphercloud as well. Was this issue resolved?